# Android get json elements

Tags: android, json, string

I am implementing the moethod to get json cel l content through google spreadsheet

The below is the part of my content

```
    [{"scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"traditional"},
"content":{"type":"text","$t":"ridicule: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/369.gif, adore: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/adore.gif, agree: http://hkgalden
.com/face/hkg/agree.gif, angel: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/a
ngel.gif, angry: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/angry
.gif, ass: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/ass.gif, banghead: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/
banghead.gif, biggrin: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/biggrin.gif
```

When it comes to using the following methods to extract link as follows

from

```
biggrin: http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/biggrin.gif
```

to

```
http://hkgalden.com/face/hkg/biggrin.gif
```

Using

```
                        link = data[0].split(": ")[1];
```

It sometimes cannot get the values and hence insert the data record using ORMLite
and found empty data link
What should I follow afterwords?

Is using substring with lastOfIndex can help ?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to parse json file? Why are you not using json-parser then? Something like Gson library: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: It is OK for me to parse the values directly but seems writing to SQLITE database seems be the problem. I wonder if such method being mentioned will extract null or blank values